# HTML, Javascript, and PHP - maxlength able to be changed through inspect element

Tags: javascript, php, html, maxlength

Back with an issue which I'm sure you guys will find easy to fix. Whilst using the maxlength function in html, I noticed that users can simply use inspect element to modify the maxlength deeming it pretty useless.

Basic example of max-length:

```html
<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="250" alt="Please don't change my maxlength">
```

I'm looking for a solution in Javascript or PHP at preventing this code manipulation on the server side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Important validation _always_ needs to happen on the server side. It would be naive to assume that any request reaching your server would have to have originated in something called a "browser" to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point trying to work around this in JS as users can simply bypass your validation code and manually submit a form to your site which has a value longer than the specified `maxlength`. So you need to deal with it in PHP:

```php
$username = $_POST['username'] ?? '';
if (strlen($username) > 250) {
    // return some sort of error to the user
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure input sanitization and validation on server-side, client-side is not always  secure. Like below code block but need more improvement

https://www.php.net/manual/tr/filter.filters.sanitize.php

```php
$input = trim($_POST["YOUR_INPUT"]); // clear left and right whitespaces
$input = filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //sanitize input

if(mb_strlen($input)>=255){
  return "Input can not be longer than 255 chars.";
}
```